# bundler 1.15.0 omniauth-cas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm suddenly having issues running my rails app after bundler 1.15.0 came out.  I'd prefer not to have to downgrade to bundler 1.14.6 as our deploy tools automatically retrieve the latest version of bundler.

Here's the output I'm seeing when I run `rails s`:

```
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'omniauth-cas'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `option' for OmniAuth::Strategies::CAS:Class
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/omniauth-cas-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategies/cas.rb:19:in `<class:CAS>'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing everything out of your /tmp/cache folder. You could also try running `bundle exec rails s` to make sure bundler runs the server with the correct context

Comment: Thanks, I wish that would've helped, but sadly it didn't.